# jquery tooltip individual delay for different types

Tags: jquery, tooltip, delay

I just took a look at the tooltips from jquery-ui and I have the following code going on:

```
$(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({
            items: "[tooltip], [title]",
            content: function() {
                var element = $( this );
                if ( element.is( "[tooltip]" ) )
                {
                    var id = element.attr( "tooltip" );
                    return $("#tooltip_"+id)[0].innerHTML;
                }
                if ( element.is( "[title]" ) )
                {
                    return element.attr( "title" );
                }
            },
            show: {
                effect: "slideDown"
            }
        });
    });
```

It works and it does what it should.
The reason i have implemented different methods for if it's a tooltip with a "tooltip" attribute or a "title" attribute is as follows:
If it's a "tooltip" attribute there is only an id and somewhere in the page is a div-element containing the content of the tooltip (it's a table with stuff in it).
But if it's a "title" attribute I want the usual behavior.

However, I want to define different delays to the tooltips defined by "tooltip" or "title" attributes.
E.g. if it's a "tooltip" tooltip I want a delay of 200ms and if it's a "title" tooltip I want 500ms.

I have no idea how to do it.
I know that if i add `delay: 500` after `effect: "slideDown"` the delay for ALL tooltips will be 500ms but I don't know how to do it individually.

I hope I didn't bother you with such a long text and you understand my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is simply use `.tooltip()` twice.

```
$(function () {
    $(document)
        .tooltip({
            items: "[tooltip]",
            content: function () {
                var $element = $(this);
                var id = $element.attr("tooltip");
                return $("#tooltip_" + id).html();
            },
            show: {
                effect: "slideDown",
                duration: 200
            }
        })
        .tooltip({
            items: "[title]",
            content: function () {
                var $element = $(this);
                return $element.attr("title");
            },
            show: {
                effect: "slideDown",
                duration: 500
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. Only the last call of tooltip() is used. I guess it just overwrites the data, set by the previous call.